# What is the chat score?

Tags: discussion, chat

Could sound trivial but sometimes along with a chat entry from a user, below the profile picture, comes a number.

I cannot sort out what that number stands for. I noticed that it also features in user profile on the chat.stackexchange but honestly I don't understand it.

Could anyone exaplain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the [user's network-wide reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77479/what-is-the-number-next-to-my-name-in-chat), [less association bonuses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123468/should-the-account-association-bonuses-be-excluded-when-calculating-totals-for-c).

Comment: how is it computed? And also, is it restricted to a single SE branch?

Comment: "Network-wide" means across all StackExchange sites. It's a straight sum of all your accounts, as far as I know.

Comment: I had the same guess but looking at my profile accounts I should have > 2k score while in the chat profile it is close to 1.4k. So I wondered if it is calculaded in another way

Comment: giving a better look at my profile page I realized that the score in the chat match the top 3 account scores of the user. If you think it is reasonable could you edit your answer so that I can accept?

Comment: It probably doesn't count association bonus then.